# Действие при изменении размеров окна

Tags: java

Подскажите, ребята. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы перерисовывался фрейм каждый раз при изменении размеров окна. У меня, например, будет изменятся график, в зависимости от того, какую сторону мы вытянули. Есть ли для этого стандартный метод или нужно создавать свой?

Answer (score 1):

Смотри в сторону [ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html)'а

Comment: Ага, спасибо, сейчас почитаю...

Comment: Спасибо еще раз, идею понял, думаю ваш ответ поможет мне решить задачу!